# Export data to CSV file?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
string = 
"""MNRGVPFRHLLLVLQLALLPAATQGKKVVLGKKGDTVELTCTASQKKSIQFHWKNSNQIK
ILGNQGSFLTKGPSKLNDRADSRRSLWDQGNFPLIIKNLKIEDSDTYICEVEDQKEEVQL
LVFGLTANSDTHLLQGQSLTLTLESPPGSSPSVQCRSPRGKNIQGGKTLSVSQLELQDSG
TWTCTVLQNQKKVEFKIDIVVLAFQKASSIVYKKEGEQVEFSFPLAFTVEKLTGSGELWW
QAERASSSKSWITFDLKNKEVSVKRVTQDPKLQMGKKLPLHLTLPQALPQYAGSGNLTLA
LEAKTGKLHQEVNLVVMRATQLQKNLTCEVWGPTSPKLMLSLKLENKEAKVSKREKAVWV
LNPEAGMWQCLLSDSGQVLLESNIKVLPTWSTPVQPMALIVLGGVAGLLLFIGLGIFFCV
RCRHRRRQAERMSQIKRLLSEKKTCQCPHRFQKTCSPI"""

for n in range(len(string)-16):
    if len(string[n:n+16]) == 16:
        print(string[n:n+16])
    else:
        break
```

I want to be able to then write the results of the loop to a csv file.
How would I do that?

Comment: read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Read the docs not very helpful. Already read them and as I didn't understand I asked here..

Comment: A CSV file is a text file composed of rows of data where each row consists of one or more fields of data each separated (delimited) by a character, often a comma `,`. Please [edit] your question and describe what you like the delimiter to be and what the fields of each row should be—this cannot be determined from the code it currently contains.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is just a file format, see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values
So you can use file i/o built in python or you can use pandas, a python library for processing data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> def chunks(f, n):
...    for i in range(0, len(f), n):
...       yield f[i:i+n]
...
>>> with open('file.csv', 'w') as w:
...   for row in chunks(s.replace('\n',''), 16)):
...      w.write('{}\n'.format(row))
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
def write_into_csv_file(file_path,array):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(array)
string = 'sjhdfakjhdfkajhdfakjhdfakjfhaksjfhasdfkjaskjfh'
ls=[]
for n in range(len(string)-16):
    if len(string[n:n+16]) == 16:
    ls.append(string[n:n+16])
    print(string[n:n+16])
else:
    break
write_into_csv_file('hello.csv',ls)
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for actually trying to be helpful!

for some reason it doesn't like it when I put the file path in?

def write_into_csv_file("/home/chris/Desktop/BioPythonWork", array):

Comment: where is the file name `something.csv` ?